# How to call a method of a derived class whose base class is ResourceTestCase

Tags: django, python-2.7, tastypie

I have written some tast cases in *SomeClass* Class and its working competely fine,for this test cases I am using 2 methods *anyMethod* and *anotherMethod*

> ```
> from tastypie.test import ResourceTestCase
> from members.models import Org
>
> class SomeClass(ResourceTestCase):
>     fixtures = ['anyfixture']
>     def setUp(self):
>         super(SomeClass, self).setUp()
>         self.webmaster_username = 'webmaster@gm.com'
>         self.webmaster_password = '123'
>     def anyMethod():
>         self.api_client.client.login(username=self.webmaster_username,
>                                  password=self.webmaster_password)
>     def anotherMethod(dataDump):
>         self.anyMethod()
>
>         self.response = self.api_client.post(self.get_detail_url, format='json', data=dataDump)
>         #More steps in function
> ```

What I am want is that, I have another Class named *AnotherClass* in that I want to call method *anotherMethod*  from the *SomeClass*

```
from tastypie.test import ResourceTestCase
from members.models import Org

class AnotherClass(ResourceTestCase):
    fixtures = ['fixture23']
    def setUp(self):
        super(AnotherClass, self).setUp()
        self.admin_username = 'admin@gm.com'
        self.admin_password = '123'
        #here I Need to call method anotherMethod from class SomeClass.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inherit AnotherClass from SomeClass:

```
class AnotherClass(SomeClass):
    fixtures = ['fixture23']
    def setUp(self):
        super(AnotherClass, self).setUp()
        self.admin_username = 'admin@gm.com'
        self.admin_password = '123'
        self.anotherMethod(self.fixtures)
```